# Convert from format with 5 exponent bits to format with 4 exponent bits

Tags: binary, rounding, ieee-754

Consider the following two 9-bit floating-point representations based on the IEEE floating-point
format.

**Format A:**

There is 1 sign bit.

There are k = 5 exponent bits. The exponent bias is 15.

There are n = 3 fraction bits.

**Format B:**

There is 1 sign bit.

There are k = 4 exponent bits. The exponent bias is 7.

There are n = 4 fraction bits.

In the following table, you are given some bit patterns in format A, and your task is to convert
them to the closest value in format B. In
addition, give the values of numbers given by the format A and format B bit patterns

I'm currently stuck on 3 cases:

| Format A | Value | Format B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 00111 010 | -5/1024 |  |  |
| 0 00000 111 | 7/131072 |  |  |
| 1 11100 000 | -8192 |  |  |

I am able to convert to decimal value for all 3 cases, but I am struggling to convert format B.

The first case if I change to format B, the exponent with bias will be -8 + bias = -8 + 7 = -1, so is it correct if I make the exponent all 0 (denormalized value)? And how will be the frac part?

The second case I think it is right to make the exp all 0 (denormalized value), but what is the correct frac part?

The last case, the exponent overflows (since 13 + 7 = 20 which exceeds 4-bit), so what should it be?

I really need to understand how this works, not only the answer. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The exponent field encodes an exponent. The code 0 means subnormal. The code 1 is the minimum normal exponent. With a bias of 7, the code of 1 encodes an exponent of 1−7 = −6. Therefore, the minimum exponent is −6. To encode a subnormal number, you need to adjust its exponent to be −6.

The value −5/1024 equals −101<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−10</sup>. Shifting to make its exponent −6 gives −101<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−10</sup> = −0.0101<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−6</sup>. So the leading bit of the significand is 0 (confirming it is subnormal), and the trailing bits are 0101.

For 7/131,072, shifting to make the exponent −6 gives 111<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−13</sup> = 0.0000111<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−6</sup>. The significand does not fit into five bits (one leading plus four trailing), so this number cannot be represented in the format. Rounding to the nearest representable value gives 0.0001<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−6</sup>.

For −8192, shifting to make the exponent the largest representable value, 7, gives −1<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>13</sup> = −1000000<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>7</sup>. So this number cannot be represented in the format. Rounding is implemented by choosing the rounding direction as if the exponent range were unbounded. So this should be rounded upward in magnitude (downward when the sign is conisdered). Rounding upward in magnitude from the largest finite value produces infinity. So this number is rounded to −∞, which is represented with the sign bit set, all ones in the exponent field, and all zeros in the primary significand field.